# Juliet test suite result validation

Tags: java, jenkins-pipeline, benchmarking, test-suite, sast

During my examination of the manifest.xml file in the Juliet Java Test Suite. I discovered some infractions are out of sync. I want to compare the output from the sast tool with the anticipated outcome (the Juliet manifest file). what location is the extract manifest file?